# SSL Error while Sending Email with Python (Raspbian OS)

Tags: python, email, raspbian

I just write this code in Python under Raspbian OS:

```
import smtplib

fromaddr = '*****@hotmail.de'
toaddrs  = '*****@hotmail.de'
msg = 'Testmail'

username = '*****@hotmail.de'
password = '*****'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com',587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

And get following Error-Message:

```
python ail.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ail.py", line 14, in <module>
  server.login(username, password)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 601, in login
  AUTH_PLAIN + " " + encode_plain(user, password))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 385, in docmd
  return self.getreply()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 358, in getreply
  + str(e))
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1359: 
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

What is my fault? Could somebody help me - please?

Regards

Comment: @MaximeLorant: no, it's not a dup; this is the new problem that he tried to change that question into after getting an answer to that one.

Comment: @abarnert Oh yeah indeed... The title and the post are nearly the same, I was confused...

Comment: This _does_ appear to be a dup of [SSL error on Raspberry Pi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031122/ssl-error-on-raspberry-pi). But nobody found an answer to that problem. It appears to be something funky about Microsoft's server, which might or might not be solvable by using Python 3.3's expanded SSL support, but since the OP gave us and switched to gmail nobody found out.

Comment: At any rate, please try the test steps from that question—and also try running your code on your desktop system to see if there's anything specific to Rasp going on.

Comment: so I didn't have a chance to send this damn mail?

Comment: @user1557170: If there's a bug with Hotmail's SMTP SSL support, and nobody has bothered to figure out a workaround from the client side in Python 2.7, and you're not willing to do the work to try to debug the problem yourself, then I guess you didn't.

Comment: I do to try it by myself. Now I tried to use my icloud account and get a different error message: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ail.py", line 15, in <module>
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 737, in sendmail
    raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550, '5.7.0 From address is not one of your addresses.')

Comment: vote to reopen. @m59: The problems are different (shadowing stdlib module vs. ssl error). The question titles could be edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

After I've signed in on `http://live.com` and validated my account; your code worked as is on Ubuntu python 2.7 and python3.3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Send email via live.com."""
import smtplib
from email.mime.text      import MIMEText
from email.header         import Header

login, password = ...

msg = MIMEText(u'body…', 'plain', 'utf-8')
msg['Subject'] = Header(u'subject…', 'utf-8')
msg['From'] = login
recipients = [login]
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com', 587, timeout=10)  
s.set_debuglevel(1)
try:
    s.starttls() 
    s.login(login, password) 
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], recipients, msg.as_string())
finally:
    s.quit()
```

Check whether `openssl` can connect to it (`ca-certificates` is installed and it is not [this bug](http://cvs.openssl.org/chngview?cn=22565)):

```
$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.live.com:587
```

If it is successful; you could replace [`smtplib.SMTP.starttls()` method](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/smtplib.py#l618) (in a subclass) to set appropriate ssl parameters.