# python: sending a mail, fails when inside a "with" block

Tags: email, python-3.x, gmail, raspberry-pi, with-statement

I am wondering why this code

```
test = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
test.ehlo()
test.starttls()
test.ehlo()
test.login('address','passw')
test.sendmail(sender, recipients, composed)
test.close()
```

works, but when written like this

```
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as s:
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.ehlo()
    s.login('address','passw')
    s.sendmail(sender, recipients, composed)
    s.close()
```

it fails with the message

```
Unable to send the email. Error:  <class 'AttributeError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py_script.py", line 100, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as s:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Why is this happening? (python3 on a raspberry pi)
Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using Python 3.3 or up. In your version of Python, `smtplib.SMTP()` is not a context manager and cannot be using in a `with` statement.

The traceback is directly caused because there is no [`__exit__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__exit__), a requirement for context managers.

From the [`smptlib.SMTP()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP):

> *Changed in version 3.3*: Support for the `with` statement was added.

You can wrap the object in a context manager with [`@contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from smtplib import SMTPResponseException, SMTPServerDisconnected

@contextmanager
def quitting_smtp_cm(smtp):
    try:
        yield smtp
    finally:
        try:
            code, message = smtp.docmd("QUIT")
            if code != 221:
                raise SMTPResponseException(code, message)
        except SMTPServerDisconnected:
            pass
        finally:
            smtp.close()
```

This uses the same exit behaviour as was added in Python 3.3. Use it like this:

```
with quitting_smtp_cm(smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)) as s:
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.ehlo()
    s.login('address','passw')
    s.sendmail(sender, recipients, composed)
```

Note that it'll close the connection for you.

Comment: Then this is wrong (?) http://robertwdempsey.com/python3-email-with-attachments-using-gmail/

Comment: But in python3? I'm trying it in version 3 EDIT:ok, I have python 3.2.3, thanks :)

Comment: @Gerard: The documentation states it was made a context manager in Python 3.3.

Comment: @Gerard: I added a work-around for you; but you probably want to upgrade to Python 3.3 or 3.4.

Comment: Thanks for being so fast :D
*I see that 3.4 is under "testing" and not in "stable" yet (https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=python3)

Comment: @Gerard: you could use `contextlib.closing()` instead of creating your own context manager if you need to call `.close()`. I usually [call `.quit()` here instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20755265/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `.close()` is not enough as it won't send the `QUIT` message, and `.quit()` doesn't handle an already closed connection (perhaps there was a network error). In an exit handler you need to handle that case cleanly.